# How to get the xpath for UI Automator Viewer for mobile automation?

Tags: android, xpath, appium

In My app, I dont have Resource ID for almost all buttons. In that case how I can perform the action on UI Elements ?

I have tried with Appium UI Inspector which gives me xpath which is too length to use.

What is the procedure to generate the Standard XPath from UIAutomator Viewer ?

Comment: did u find a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Please try this [Link](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/10/ui-automator-viewer-get-android-app.html])

UI Automator Viewer : Get Android App Element's XPath, ID, Name And className

Comment: the link is not found !